# How to insert 0 or NA while reshaping data in R when the key variable has different length across a given group

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-manipulation

Bellow it is my data structure (df). The objective is converting data from long to wide separating by variable "status" (df.long) using R. I am aware that status "a" and "b" does not repeat in all the months.

| year | month | status | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 1 | a | 10 |
| 2018 | 1 | b | 2 |
| 2018 | 2 | a | 9 |
| 2018 | 3 | a | 13 |
| 2018 | 3 | b | 1 |

For this I use this code in R:

```
df.long <- df %>% spread(df, key = status, value = n)
```

It is OK except by the fact that when there is no status in a given month (ex.: status "b" for the month "2" from the above example), it returns in characters that are inserted in the cells with no "status" [characters such as `c("2018", "2019"...)`].

The question is: how to code this to replace with *NA* or 0 when there is no status value in a given month?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot_wider()` instead of `spread()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% pivot_wider(everything(), names_from = "status", values_from = "n")

# A tibble: 3 x 4
   year month     a     b
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1  2018     1    10     2
2  2018     2     9    NA
3  2018     3    13     1
```

You can take a look at the [documentation](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) where it stated:

> pivot_wider() is an updated approach to spread(), designed to be both simpler to use and to handle more use cases. We recommend you use pivot_wider() for new code; spread() isn't going away but is no longer under active development.

Comment: You can accept my answer by clicking the little tick mark on the left have side of the answer if it helped :)